# Stochastic Gradient Descent with constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization, random, machine-learning, neural-networks

Let's say we have a convex objective function $f(\textbf{x})$, with $\textbf{x}\in R^n$ which we want to minimise under a set of constraints. The problem is that calculating $f$ *exactly* is not possible and only stochastic approximations are available, which are computably expensive.

Luckily the gradient $\nabla f$ can also be approximated such that we can use a [stochastic gradient descent method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent):

$$\textbf{x}^{(k+1)}=\mathbf{x}^{(k)}-\alpha^{(k)} \nabla f(\textbf{x})$$
where $\alpha^{(k)}$ is the step size and $\nabla f(\mathbf{x})$ is the *approximated* gradient of $f(\mathbf{x})$.

---

**My question**

This method is fast since it still converges even when the accuracy of the gradient is relatively low. But this will give an unconstrained solution, i.e., I will need that,

$$
x_j=0 \lor \alpha_j \le x_j \le \beta_j\quad \text{for all } \ \ j, \ \text{ and }\sum_j x_j \le 1
$$

where $\alpha_j$ and $\beta_j$ are minimum and maximum constraints such that $0<\alpha_j, \beta_j\le 1$.

Is there a way to use Mathematica's built in functions such as `FindMinimum[]` or `Minimize[]` to carry out a stochastic gradient descent (or any other method that will solve this problem).

---

**Toy code**

```
p = {.47, .53, .48, .31, .255, .27, .27, .311, .31, .466, .371, .304};
b = {2.5, 2, 2.2, 3.5, 4.33, 4, 4, 3.4, 3.4, 2.2, 2.7, 3.3};

z[o_, b_] := If[o == 1, b - 1, -1];
n = Length[p];
M = 10000;

outcomes = Transpose[Table[RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[1,{p[[i]], 1 - p[[i]]}], M], {i, n}]];

f[x_] := Block[{Y, R}, Mean[Reap[Do[Y = outcomes[[K]];R = 1 + Sum[z[Y[[i, 1]], b[[i]]] x[[i]], {i, n}]; Sow[-Log[R]];, {K, M}]][[2,1]]]]
```

Comment: Can you post your code, with approximated `f`, so that people have something to play around with?

Comment: No, there are no builtin functions for any of this. You'll need to implement it yourself.  This is an interesting question (at least I'm personally interested), but it doesn't seem to be related to Mathematica. Maybe a better fit on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: [`BayesianMinimization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BayesianMinimization.html) attempts to find a good minimum using the smallest number of evaluations.  Probably you can implement a [Bayesian Optimization with Gradients](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04389). Probably by defining a good *`sampler`*. Actually I don't know much about this problem, so I may be saying something stupid.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for your reply, I thought as much but it couldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Your f[x] sometimes returns real values, sometimes returns Indeterminate, and sometimes complexes. You are going to need to fix that to have much hope of finding minima.

Comment: @bills given the constraints that x_j>0 for all j, and sum_j x_j<1 the function should behave.

Comment: One way you could use NMinimize would be to translate the constraints into part of the cost function: for example, penalize deviation from sum x<1 and deviation below alpha and above beta. Then you can weight the various parts of the cost to ensure you fulfill the constraints.